# I want to stop closing the side menu

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

hope somebody can give me a hint. 
I use the Ionic Side Menu (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/) and want reload the menu after clicking on an item.
My problem is, that the menu get closed after clicking on an item. How can I stop that?
Cant find the right event in the angular directives.

Regards 
Benedikt

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

```
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
```

You can toggle the sidemenu

EDIT: try removing the `menu-close` in the sidemenu `<a href="#/item" class="item" menu-close>Item</a>` if you remove that, the menu is not going to close

Comment: Thanks. I already have this in my code, but I not want to toggle it, I want to open it and than it should stay open until I call a close function.

Comment: @user3629980 try removing the `menu-close` in the sidemenu `<a href="#/item" class="item" menu-close>Item</a>` if you remove that, the menu is not going to close